# How to I merge two or more cells if they have the same content on other cells

Tags: excel, vba, merge-conflict-resolution

I wanted to see if there is an easier way through an if(), VBA, or array formula to merge/sum cells with the same title. What I want is if the name matches, to merge the IDs together with a "," in one cell, then sum the rooms and SF together into one row together.

```
 ID                 Name                  Rooms    Sf
 00000121856000000  Dreadfall Apartments   123     44000
 00000121865000000  Dreadfall Apartments   115     40000
 00000121898000000  Clear Creek             22     11500
 00000121897000000  Clear Creek             22     11500
 00000121541000000  Clear Creek             23     12500
```

I want it to look like:

```
|00000121856000000, 00000121865000000                  | Dreadfall  Apartments  | 238 | 84000
|00000121898000000,00000121897000000, 00000121541000000| Clear Creek            |  67 | 58500
```

Assume "ID" is A1 and "Sf" is D1. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  SO is not a code for me site nor is it a teach me to code site.  what have you tried?  If you are using Office 365 Excel 2016 then most likely this can be done with an array formula or two and some SUMIFS().  Otherwise you will need to sort your data and use a helper column to do formulas.  If none of those will work then you are stuck with vba.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you!!

```
Sub Macro()
Dim lngRow As Long
For lngRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
If StrComp(Range("B" & lngRow), Range("B" & lngRow - 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
If Range("C" & lngRow) <> "" Then
Range("A" & lngRow - 1) = Range("A" & lngRow - 1) & ";" & Range("A" & lngRow)
Range("C" & lngRow - 1) = Range("C" & lngRow - 1) + Range("C" & lngRow)
Range("D" & lngRow - 1) = Range("D" & lngRow - 1) + Range("D" & lngRow)
End If
Rows(lngRow).Delete
End If
Next
End Sub
```